# solve the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x''=2x^2+4txx'$ $0\leq t\leq 1$

where  $x(0)=1/4$ and $x(1)=1/3$

how to solve analytically? 
Mathmatica and Matlab not able to solve this equation

Comment: Does $tx^2$ ring any bell to you?

Comment: Following Troy's hint, if $u = tx^2$, $u' = x^2 + 2txx'$. Hence we rewrite the ODE as $x'' = 2u'$. Integrating once, $$x' = 2u + c = 2tx^2 + c$$

Now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$RHS= \frac{d(2tx^2)}{dt}$, so integrate both sides to get: $dx/dt = 2tx^2+c_1$, which is a Riccati's equation, work from there.

Comment: @Harish Also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Obtaining_solutions_by_quadrature). One particular solution can be easily found in your case.

Comment: I don't see it. I would be curious to see the solution to this problem.

Comment: let $c_1$ be $0$ for now, then do the usual things will get you to $x=1/(c_2-t^2)$, then you can do what Troy Woo said as above, or you can just try if this solution will fit the boundary conditions or not, it turns out it fits the conditions and $c_2 =4$, so  $x=1/(4-t^2)$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t)=2(x(t))^2+4tx(t)\frac{d}{dt}x(t) $$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t)=2\left((x(t))^2+2tx(t)\frac{d}{dt}x(t)\right)$$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t)=2\left((x(t))^2\frac{d}{dt}t+t\frac{d}{dt}\left[(x(t))^2\right]\right)$$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t)=2\frac{d}{dt}\left[t(x(t))^2\right] $$
$$ d\left(\frac{d}{dt}x(t)\right)=2\ d\left[t(x(t))^2\right] $$
$$ \int d\left(\frac{d}{dt}x(t)\right)=2\int \ d\left[t(x(t))^2\right] $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}x(t)=2t(x(t))^2+C $$
Can you take it from here?